# D3 area chart filling above the line

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart, area-chart

I'm trying to create a d3 area chart with a gradient area fill. But if the graph data starts or ends at value anything other than 0 then the area fills above the line.
Here is the working fiddle with the code.

https://jsfiddle.net/damamgova/dhLb67mt/

```
var svg = d3.select("#" + id)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.value = d.value;
});
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    // Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
const maxY = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; });
// Add the valueline path.
svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("stroke", color)
    .attr("stroke-width", 3)
    .attr("fill", "url(#gradient)")
    .attr("d", valueline(data));

// Add Gradient
svg.append("linearGradient")
    .attr("id", "gradient")
    .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
    .attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", y(0))
    .attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", y(maxY))
    .selectAll("stop")
    .data([
        { offset: "0%", color: "transparent" },
        { offset: "50%", color: color + "50" },
        { offset: "100%", color: color }
    ])
    .enter().append("stop")
    .attr("offset", function(d) { return d.offset; })
    .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d.color; });

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining an `area` path generator, but are not using it to generate the path for your line.

Instead, (in your fiddle, but not in the code above) you have defined a line generator called `valueline` and are using that to generate the path.

If there is a fill, the *line generator* will close the line end with the line start and fill in the enclosed space, which is why you are seeing the fill above the line.

With the *area generator* you specify the `y0` property, which in the case of your chart will simply be the bottom of the chart. The outputted path will then close along the base-line and any applied fill will be for the whole area.

Your path definition using the area path generator would be simply:

```
svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("stroke", color)
  .attr("stroke-width", 3)
  .attr("fill", "url(#gradient)")
  .attr("d", area(data));
```

There is an issue with this though, and that is that as you are not using a solid fill for your area and you *are* using a stroke, the bottom edge of the area will also be stroked. You could add a couple of pixels onto the height of the `y0` parameter of your `area` function so that the x axis covers it...

https://jsfiddle.net/qp8xvhaL/

Comment: Yes, that's what I did finally. :P